# dash app not rendering

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm making a dash (by plotly) app using python. When I try to run it in the browser, I'm able to get it to run locally but none of my csv data actually renders (I just see the blank axes in the background. The only one i'm interested in is the first one (the ufo map). The others I didn't create the callbacks for.

Here is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from flask_caching import Cache
from csv import DictReader
from toolz import compose, pluck, groupby, valmap, first, unique, get, 
countby
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

listpluck = compose(list, pluck)
listfilter = compose(list, filter)
listmap = compose(list, map)
listunique = compose(list, unique)

TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"

df = pd.read_csv('ufo_sightings.csv')

# Datetime helpers.
def sighting_year(sighting):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(sighting[df['date_time']], 
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT).year

def sighting_dow(sighting):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(sighting[df['date_time']], 
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT)\
                  .strftime("%a")


def ufo_map(sightings):
    classifications = groupby('shape', sightings)
    return {
    "data": [
            {
                "type": "scattermapbox",
                "lat": listpluck("city_latitude", class_sightings),
                "lon": listpluck("city_longitude", class_sightings),
                "text": listpluck("summary", class_sightings),
                "mode": "markers",
                "name": shape,
                "marker": {
                    "size": 3,
                    "opacity": 1.0
                }
            }
            for shape, class_sightings in classifications.items()
        ],
    "layout": {
        "autosize": True,
        "hovermode": "closest",
        "mapbox": {
            "accesstoken": os.environ.get("MAPBOX_KEY"),
            "bearing": 0,
            "center": {
                "lat": 40,
                "lon": -98.5
            },
            "pitch": 0,
            "zoom": 2,
            "style": "outdoors"
        }
    }
}


reader = DictReader(df)
BFRO_LOCATION_DATA = [
line for line in reader ]

app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server
server.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", "secret")

app.title = "UFO Sightings"
cache = Cache(app.server, config={"CACHE_TYPE": "simple"})


@cache.memoize(10)
def filter_sightings(filter_text):
    return listfilter(
        lambda x: filter_text.lower() in x['summary'].lower(),
        BFRO_LOCATION_DATA

    )

app.layout = html.Div([
# Row: Title
html.Div([
    # Column: Title
    html.Div([
        html.H1("UFO Sightings", className="text-center")
    ], className="col-md-12")
], className="row"),
# Row: Filter + References
html.Div([
    # Column: Filter
    html.Div([
        html.P([
            html.B("Filter the titles:  "),
            dcc.Input(
                placeholder="Try 'saw'",
                id="ufo-text-filter",
                value="")
        ]),
    ], className="col-md-6"),
    # Column: References.
    html.Div([
        html.P([
            "Data pulled from ",
            html.A("nuforc.org", href="http://www.nuforc.org/"),
            ". Grab it at ",
            html.A("data.world", 
href="https://data.world/timothyrenner/ufo-sightings"),
            "."
        ], style={"text-align": "right"})
    ], className="col-md-6")
], className="row"),
# Row: Map + Bar Chart
html.Div([
    # Column: Map
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id="ufo-map")
    ], className="col-md-8"),
    # Column: Bar Chart
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id="ufo-dow")
    ], className="col-md-4")
], className="row"),
# Row: Line Chart + Donut Chart
html.Div([
    # Column: Line Chart
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id="ufo-by-year")
    ], className="col-md-8"),
    # Column: Donut Chart
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id="ufo-class")
    ], className="col-md-4")
], className="row"),
# Row: Footer
html.Div([
    html.Hr(),
    html.P([
        "A Deplorable Snowflake Production",
        html.A("blank", 
href="https://blank.org"),

    ])      
], className="row",
    style={
        "textAlign": "center",
        "color": "Gray"
    })
], className="container-fluid")


@app.callback(
    Output('ufo-map', 'figure'),
[
    Input('ufo-text-filter', 'value')
]
)


def filter_ufo_map(filter_text):
    return ufo_map(filter_sightings(filter_text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in 
__call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in 
handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in 
reraise
raise value
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in 
handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in 
reraise
raise value
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in 
dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 558, in dispatch
return self.callback_map[target_id]['callback'](*args)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 515, in 
add_context
output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/alien.py", line 220, in filter_ufo_map
return ufo_map(filter_sightings(filter_text))
File "/alien.py", line 47, in ufo_map
classifications = groupby('shape', sightings)
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/toolz/itertoolz.py", line 93, in 
groupby
d[key(item)](item)
KeyError: 'shape'
```

Any help here would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using `pdb` to inspect the value of `item` when the exception is thrown is likely to be enlightening.

Comment: Is it possible that `ufo_sightings.csv` has no column `shape`? Can you share some example data from the file or link the file?